# how to forbid img file to rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess

my domain in my pc is : http://www.laji.com
there are 2 files under the www folder

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# All other pages
# Don't rewrite real files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(\.css|\.js|\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

index.php

```
<?php echo $_GET['main_page'] ?>
```

when I visit http://wwww.laji.com/xxx.jpg (this jpg is not exist) , it rewrite to index.php?main_page=xxx.jpg , but I want to let it display 404 infomation, no need to rewrite , why my htaccess code don't work?

Comment: I get a 404 when I go to a jpg that doesn't exists using your rules

Comment: @mingfish_004 Is this the only code in your htaccess or you have other rules also?

Comment: Can you try `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` on top of your .htaccess replacing your Options line.

Comment: tried, the same result

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(\.css|\.js|\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg)$
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$
```

and let me know if it's working.

If not working, I think you may need to add a line (near the top of the .htaccess) like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Not found!"
```

If you get it working, you may add a custom error 404 file like that (instead of the above text in quotes):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html
```

Reference: [Set web server handle 404 errors for some file types using .htaccess (ErrorDocument 404 + rewrite rules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180988/set-web-server-handle-404-errors-for-some-file-types-using-htaccess-errordocum)